# Why would Clausius define the change in entropy $∆S$ as $Q/T$?

Tags: theoretical-physics

Why Clausius defined entropy this way?

Comment: He didn't. He defined $dS$ as $dQ/T$, and even Wikipedia explains why, see [Clausius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem): in a reversible cyclic process $\int dQ/T=0$, "so the fact that this integral is equal to zero per cycle in a reversible process implies that there is some function (entropy) whose infinitesimal change is $dQ/T$."